# How to hardcode WordPress blog meta tags?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, google-news

I've tried searching for everything possible. I couldn't find a way to add `<meta name="news_keyword">` in my blog post page. I also tried editing my blogs hardcoding but failed to do so.

I found Yoast's news plugin which does help me do my job, but it's $69 which being just a small blog site owner I cannot afford.

Comment: What is "Blog Meta Tags" you are referring?

Comment: This is probably just a theme edit. I expect a child theme would be a good idea, so you can override just the file you need.